# moveRow(at:to:) doesn't work if the UITableView has many items

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, swift3

I'm trying to animate move items between sections after selecting row.
This is code I'm using for moving items from section 0 to section 1:

```
tableSource[indexPath.section].tableItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableSource[1].tableItems.insert(data, at: 0)
tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1))
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
 })
```

DispatchQueue is used to update row after animation.

It works perfectly if all items fit in the screen or if section 1 is visible. Otherwise, I get the behavior as when you delete a row and add it to another index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because UITableView doesn't know where to animate if cell isn't visible

Comment: Am also facing the same problem, Is it possible to solve this. Any idea? I want to animate tableview cell even if the cell is not visible.

Comment: @Madhavan I have no idea. Only hard custom layout I think.